How to see comments left in Staging Ground?
After I've left a comment for someone to improve their question, I like to go back after some time and see if they've addressed my concerns.  This works great for regular questions, I can go to my profile and see the comments I've left.  But comments on Staging Ground questions don't appear in that list so I don't have a link back to those questions.  How can I see those comments?

Seeing your own review comments as well as some other things have been requested during the beta tests and marked as [status-planned] at that time (December 2022). I don't know whether it's still on some plan.

If you left a review along with your comment you can find the Staging Ground post by opening the review history and enabling the "Show only my reviews" option. You can use this link to get to the page directly

If on the other hand you've not left a review unfortunately such actions don't show up in the activity tab yet. There is a existing feature request for it to be added though.

Edited without review also shows up as an entry in 'My Review History'.
